# Is the "by" correct in "makes no claims by writing them"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Is it correct to use the preposition "by" in such a context:

> If within this period Mr X makes no claims on the work quality **by** writing them in the certificate, then ...

I meant that Mr X can write all the claims in the certificate within the given period of time.

Comment: It is completely correct. "by the first of each month" must be used in every rental agreement I've ever entered into.

Comment: The only sense of 'by' that begins to make sense to me here is the short form of 'by means of' / 'by the expedient of'.

Answer (score 1):

This usage is correct and would mean:

> If he wants, Mr. X should make claims on the work quality by writing them in the certificate.